# Python scripts do not work by double clicking on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

**Problem**

I am not able to setup the path variables such that my scripts work by double clicking them in windows 10. I was able to do this perfectly fine until I uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda (`Python 3.7.4)`. After trouble shooting this issue with many forums and online articles, I am no more closer to the solution. I understand that my user path variables need to be set to locate python and such but that is about it. I have put in all of my path variables in `C:\Users\name\Anaconda3` also with the specified folders of `\Scripts`, `\envs`, `\Lib`, `\libs`, `\pkgs`, etc.

My scripts work fine in IDE like Spyder, the scripts are set to open with `python.exe` in the Anaconda3 folder, the Anaconda shell recognizes python, and I have read all of the other stackoverflow posts about this to no avail.

After clicking the script a terminal opens but closes immediately in which the script is supposed to run and print results in the terminal.

I ask that someone to (1) please explain to me the important aspects of setting this up so I can understand what is going on and (2) please give me some useful trouble shooting advise to solve this issue.

Thank you

---

**Update with my solution**

Looks like the single only important path to specific is:

`C:\Users\Killian\Anaconda3\Library\bin`

and now the scripts run by double clicking.

If anyone has a good explanation for this to help me and others understand this issue better, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of it, you have set up everything correctly. You must remember that the terminal will close once it has done executing the commands in your script. It is likely that that is the reason for the terminal closing. Add a line `input()` to the end of your script to hold the terminal from closing.

E.g.

A script with the one line:

`print('hello world')`

will cause the terminal to close immediately one the command is executed.

However, the script with two lines:

`print('hello world')`

`input()`

will cause the terminal to be held by the `input` command